# Reduce false detection of template matching in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I was trying to find the presence of a particular pattern in an image.
I used template matching using matchTemplate() function
But even if no such pattern is there in the image false detections are coming out.
Is there any way to filter out these false matches or is there any parameter that will tell us the percentage of correctness of the match found out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it explains in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate), the match result is calculated according to the **method** parameter you supply to the `matchTemplate` function.

You can then interpret the strength of the match accordingly.

For example, if you choose normalised cross-correlation (using `CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED` as the **method** parameter), you can expext a range of values from -1 to +1, with +1 effectively indicating a 100% match.

See [this article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) for a short tutorial. You need to supply **method** at the last parameter, so something like:

```
matchTemplate( img, temp, img_out, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED );
```

Comment: matchTemplate( img, temp, img_out, 0 ); normalize( img_out, img_out, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() ); Which parameter is to be varied NORM_MINMAX or the last parameter of matchTemplate. If latter case then which variable will give me the +1 to -1 range

Comment: @AbleEldhose no, don't call `normalize` on the output, just look at the values in `img_out`. These are the raw results of the correlation, if you normalise them, you lose what you're looking for.